# local notification control to user specified page

Tags: view, notifications, local

I am developing an IOS application with phonegap and need to set local notification for it
Once user click on "view" button need to transfer the apps control to user specified page other than "index.html"

Answer (score 0):

Since PhoneGap doesn't include currently this functionality, I'll assume your are using the LocalNotification plugin from Greg Allen & Drew Dahlman.

If you notice when you make the call to register the notification: plugins.localNotification.add() there are 2 parameters: "background" and "foreground" that contain javascript code to run when the app gets notified (in your case because it was in the background and you hit the "View" button).

Now, instead of using "app.background()" as in the example, you could pass there a Javascript code that navigates to the page you want to (or place your code in the background() function of the "app" object by editing the plugin file init.js.

For this to work make sure you have the implementation of the method didReceiveLocalNotification that comes with the plugin in the their modified AppDelegate.m class.